# How to store data with version controll and make it easy to edit and use in applications

Tags: database

I want to store a set of data (like drop tables for a game) that can be edited and "forked" (like a open source project, just data, so if I stop updating it, someone can continue with it) like a coding project. I also want that data to be easy to implement in code (for example, the same way you can use a database in code to get your values) for people that makes companion apps for said game.

What type of data storage would be the best for this scenario?

EDIT: By type of data storage I mean something Like XML or JSON or a database like Access or SQL as well as noSQL

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "forked"? And "easy to implement in code"? This is very vague at the moment

Answer (score 0):

It is a very general question, but I'm getting the feeling that you're looking for something like GitHub. If you don't know what that is, then you should probably look into it. GitHub supports svn and allows you to edit your code quite easily and let you look back to previous versions of your code. Hope this helps!